# Why we need a topological extension of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

We extend topological spaces. One point compactification is an example. But why we need this type of extension?

Answer (score 2):

Philosophically, we study an extension $\widehat{X}$ of a space $X$ because $\widehat{X}$ tells us something about the space $X$, but $\widehat{X}$ is "nicer" than $X$ in some way. "Nicer" sometimes means that invariants are easier to compute for $\widehat{X}$ than they are for $X$.

Here is perhaps the most standard application of the one point compactification.

> **Theorem.** Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers. Then $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ if and only if $n=m$.

Here is a sketch of the proof.

- If $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic topological spaces, then their one point compactifications $\widehat{X}$ and $\widehat{Y}$ are also homeomorphic.
- The one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to the $n$-sphere $S^n$ defined as
  $$S^n = \{ \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}~:~ |\mathbf{x}|=1\}.$$
- The (simplicial) homology of $S^n$ is
  $$H_i(S_n) \cong \begin{cases}
  \mathbb{Z} & i=0~\text{or}~n,\\
  0 & \text{else.}
  \end{cases}$$
- Homology is a homeomorphism invariant. Thus $S^n$ and $S^m$ are not homeomorphic if $n\neq m$, which implies the theorem.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Do you know some application of Stone -Cech compactification? I know that with the help of Stone- -Cech compactification we can characterize maximal ideals of C(X) , for some Tychonoff space X.

Comment: Applications of the Stone-Cech compactification are often in analysis (not my area of expertise). There is an interesting [StackExchange post](https://goo.gl/tQ41RU) related to the result in your comment. Maybe that will help.